# Copying timecode into output file ffmpeg or ffmbc

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have media files in various formats that I want to be able to segment using ffmbc, same acodec, vcodec and container as original. I would like to be able to maintain the timecode data e.g. start_delay, from the original to destination media files ( with the segmented offset taken into account ).

At the moment when I copy using the command `-i inputfile.mxf -vcodec copy -avodec copy outputfile.mxf` ( segmenting options omitted ) the output file start timecode is set to 00:00:00.

The original files are mainly in .mxf and .mov container formats.

Is there a command for this that I am missing?

Comment: I think there is also a type. Should -avodec be -acodec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, I clearly did not try the obvious. The command for setting the start timecode is: `-timecode HH:MM:SS:FF`